# D-Link DNS-323 NAS Drive - Can't Get Working After BT Install

Tags: networking, nas, bt-infinity

I had a modem-router with IP 192.168.0.1 which was my DHCP. My DNS-323 had a static address of 192.168.0.100 and all was well with the world:)

I recently have had BT Infinity Broadband and now I have a router with IP 192.168.1.254.

I cannot see my DNS-323 anymore. I have tried "resetting" the DNS-323 and setting it up again, but still can't see it on the network.

Any ideas about how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having logged back on to the BT Router, I noticed that there was a device I didn't recognise. Upon investigation it was the NAS with a different dynamic IP and a different name. I was then able to get to the NAS web interface and amend the IP address. All now back up and running.

@WoodE thanks for your ideas that meant that I didn't just give up

Answer (score 0):

Can you try either moving the new Router IP to 192.168.0.254 (instead of *.1.254) or moving the NAS to 192.168.1.100 and get back to us?

Comment: this was my thinking, but I am reluctant to change the default BT setup in case I lose that connectivity, but I guess I need to do this. I have been unable to connect to the NAS at all to change the IP address...any ideas how I can change the NAS IP settings

Comment: I'm assuming it has a web interface and you can't connect by typing http://192.168.0.100 in your browser?  If you're struggling to connect to it at all plug your old router back in and put your PC ethernet into that, let it set up DHCP as normal (don't bother with internet) and see if you can connect to it, change the IP, remove old router and connect back up to the new one.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try that tomorrow and let you know. Thanks